# Testing React-Navigation: how to check that screen is not focused (StackNavigator)

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-navigation

I'm trying to write tests for my react-native app that uses react-navigation (v6, but it doesn't matter).

In the example below (copied from [repo](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/packages/native-stack/src/__tests__/index.test.tsx)) I have 2 screens, and after navigating from ScreenA to ScreenB I want to check, that ScreenA is not shown anymore.

How could I do that?
I tried `expect(queryByText('Screen A')).toBeNull();` but it fails (with unrelated `Error: Couldn't find a navigation context.`).

Surprisingly `expect(queryByText('Screen A')).not.toBeNull();` passes (while I expect it to fail, since Screen A is not shown anymore).

Any clues/advices?

```
    // THE FOLLOWING LINE THROWS `Error: Couldn't find a navigation context.`
    expect(queryByText('Screen A')).toBeNull();

import { NavigationContainer, ParamListBase } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { fireEvent, render } from '@testing-library/react-native';
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator, NativeStackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

describe('welcome screen', () => {
  it('renders a native-stack navigator with screens, check first screen is NOT shown', async () => {
    const Test = ({ route, navigation }: NativeStackScreenProps<ParamListBase>) => (
      <View>
        <Text testID={`screen${route.name}`}>Screen {route.name}</Text>
        <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('A')} title="Go to A" />
        <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('B')} title="Go to B" />
      </View>
    );

    const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

    const { findByText, queryByText, getByTestId } = render(
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="A" component={Test} />
          <Stack.Screen name="B" component={Test} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );

    expect(queryByText('Screen A')).not.toBeNull();
    expect(queryByText('Screen B')).toBeNull();

    fireEvent.press(await findByText('Go to B'));

    expect(queryByText('Screen B')).not.toBeNull();

    // THE FOLLOWING LINE PASSES :)
    expect(queryByText('Screen A')).not.toBeNull();

    // THE FOLLOWING LINE THROWS `Error: Couldn't find a navigation context.`
    expect(queryByText('Screen A')).toBeNull();

  });
});
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?